# How to pick records based on specific condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table named as "ticket_lc" look like below

[image]

From the above table i need to pick only the records which satisfy the condition

condition: the ticket status should be in "assigned" and "closed" and "resolved"

so in the above table only 102 ticket is satisfying the condition, if the ticket contains other than these 3 then my query should not pick those tickets.

can anybody help me on this..!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ticket_id
FROM `project.dataset.ticket_lc`
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 3
AND COUNTIF(LOWER(status) NOT IN ('assigned', 'closed', 'resolved')) = 0
```

Yo can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.ticket_lc` AS (
  SELECT 101 ticket_id, 'Assigned' status UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'Pending' UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'Resolved' UNION ALL
  SELECT 101, 'Closed' UNION ALL
  SELECT 102, 'Assigned' UNION ALL
  SELECT 102, 'Resolved' UNION ALL
  SELECT 102, 'Closed' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Assigned' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Pending' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Pending' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Assigned' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Resolved' UNION ALL
  SELECT 103, 'Closed' 
)
SELECT ticket_id
FROM `project.dataset.ticket_lc`
GROUP BY ticket_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 3
AND COUNTIF( LOWER(status) NOT IN ('assigned', 'closed', 'resolved')) = 0
```

with result

```
Row ticket_id    
1   102
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. please consider voting up the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select ticket_id
from table t
group by ticket_id
having sum( case when status not in ('assigned', 'closed', 'resolved') then 1 else 0 end ) = 0 and
       count(*) = 3;
```

If you have a duplicate status for ticket then use `distinct` inside `count()`.

Comment: This query is picking the tickets which have "pending" status in their life cycle, if you take a ticket life cycle "pending" should not be there, i need only those tickets

Comment: . . .  That is what the query does. However, i can't argue without seeing your actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of an interesting problem. I came up with this checking if everything is covered and the amount is correct:

```sql
WITH t AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
  [struct(101 as ticket_id, 'assigned' as status),(101,'closed'),
    (102,'assigned'),(102,'resolved'),(102,'closed'),
    (104,'assigned'),(104,'assigned'),(104,'closed'),
    (103,'assigned'),(103,'pending'),(103,'pending'),(103,'assigned'),(103,'resolved'),(103,'closed')]  
  )
)

SELECT ticket_id, array_agg(distinct status) as st 
FROM t
group by 1
having (SELECT count(1)=3 FROM unnest(st) a left join unnest(['assigned','resolved','closed']) b on a=b)
```

Includes adjusted sample data to cover more problem cases.